# Service creating multiple notifications (loop)

Tags: android

My service is creating multiple notifications. I can't find why, I'm using log messages to see if there's a loop somewhere. Log cat is full of notifications so output ended is truncated.

This is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/hURHGUF.png

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.hasCategory("connection")) {
            connect();
        }
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

public void connect() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, 5000);
                socket.setSoTimeout(5000);

                connected = true;

                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String event = input.readLine();

                while (event != null) {
                    if (event.substring(0, 3).equals("msg")) {
                        Log.i("Service", "Notification");
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                                new NotificationCompat.Builder(LocalService.this)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                        .setContentTitle(event.substring(4, event.indexOf("::")))
                                        .setContentText(event.substring(event.indexOf("::") + 2));

                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(LocalService.this, ResultActivity.class);

                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(LocalService.this);
                        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                        0,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                                );
                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
                        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
                        mId = mId + 1;
                    }
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(java.net.ConnectException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

}

A single message is sent by the server, checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you should make the `String event = input.readLine();` in the `while` loop.
The code should be like this:

```
while (event != null) {
    if (event.substring(0, 3).equals("msg")) { 
        //Your normal code.
    }
    event = input.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I think event will be null at connection, so the while loop won't be initiated. I did this while (true) { String event = input.readLine(). Thanks for letting me know where the problem is!

Answer (score 1):

`while (event != null)` - loops infinitely and posts notifications. replace with `if(event != null)` instead.